# How to click a particular button after 10 minutes of loading form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have these following buttons and I want to click the approve button after l0 minutes of loading the form.

```
<input type="submit" class "button green" name "btnSend" value="Approved"/>
<input type="submit" class "button red" name "btnSend" value="Reject"/>
```

Comment: Did you forget to post the code? ;)

Comment: step 1: wait 10 minutes, step 2: click approve button, step 3: profit ... if you have a problem with step 1, most mobile devices have a stopwatch or countdown feature that can help with this

Comment: Why? Will the user know that a button will be clicked automatically? Will you show a countdown? In any case, please [edit] your question to show the code you are asking about, and to mention anything you've tried so far to implement the timer.

Comment: these are the tow button <input type="submit" class "button green" name "btnSend" value="Approved"/>
<input type="submit" class "button red" name "btnSend" value="Reject"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following:

```
// Wait for form to load
$.ready(()=>{
  setTimeout($("button.approve").click,600*1000) //click button after 10 mins.
})
```